# "B'shem Hashem" for 11 Tishre

Tags: names, calendar

Some call the eleventh of *Tishre* "*b'shem Hashem*" ("בשם ה׳"). (I assume this is a hasidic term, since, according to what I've heard, the name comes from the *Baal Shem Tov*.) Why is it called that?

Comment: Note that the moniker given in the title and question may be incorrect: See the answer and comments thereon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l, in his notes to the Chabad machzor, [quotes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32573&pgnum=328) the following explanation (printed in [Ginzei Nistaros](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21494&pgnum=42) in the name of the Baal Shem Tov):

> מה שקורין למחרת יוהכ״פ גאטש נאמען. הנה שם הוי׳ ושם קוב״ה אינו אלא מה
>   ששייך לעולם אפי׳ לעולם הנאצלים, אך לעצמותו אינו שייך לקרותו בשום שם שבעולם, והנה אם
>   פוגם הוא בשם הוי׳ דוקא וכידוע. ובימי סליחת העון יש עליות לפני הוי׳, וזה למחרת יוהכ״פ
>   אין לו שום שם פרטי לא הוי׳ ולא אדני רק גאטש נאמען, וד״ל

Paraphrasing:

The various names of Hashem are means by which created beings relate to Him; His own Essence is beyond any names. Our sins cause a blemish in the name Havayah, and during the time of forgiveness of sins [Aseres Yemei Teshuvah, or maybe more broadly also including Elul] we rise up to the level of "before [i.e., above] Havayah." Thus, the day after Yom Kippur can't be associated with any specific divine name - it's just "Hashem's Name."

---

In a footnote there, the Rebbe points out that Eshel Avraham (Buczacz, Orach Chaim 624:5) [gives](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40313&pgnum=12) a different reason, also in the name of the Baal Shem Tov: because on this day we once again begin mentioning Hashem's name where we had omitted it before, saying הא-ל הקדוש instead of המלך הקדוש.

He concludes that "these two explanations may be reconciled," but doesn't suggest how.

Comment: Thanks. The _Eshel Avraham_ calls it "shem Hashem yisbarach". While my Yiddish is poor, "גאטש נאמען" strikes me as meaning the same as "shem Hashem" also. I thought it was "b'shem Hashem" with a _bes_: is that simply an error?

Comment: @msh: dunno. The list of customs in the Machzor there says "מחרת יוהכ"פ נקרא בשם השם" - with the beis; but I don't know whether that's meant to be parsed as "is called 'B'shem Hashem'" or "is called by the name of Hashem."